# how to get information from multi websites at Simultaneous by vb.net?

Tags: vb.net

In my program, I get a series of information instantly from several Internet addresses on a one-to-one basis, but this is delay time and this delay may be part of the momentary information loss . I want to get all the  information from all URLs at the same time. Is it possible?

This is part of my program:

```
    For i As Integer = 0 To 1000
        Dim wreq As System.Net.HttpWebRequest = 

        System.Net.WebRequest.Create("http://www........." + slink(i))

        wreq.AutomaticDecompression = Net.DecompressionMethods.GZip

        Dim wres As System.Net.WebResponse = wreq.GetResponse
        Dim s As System.IO.Stream = wres.GetResponseStream
        Dim sr As New System.IO.StreamReader(s)
        Dim html As String = sr.ReadToEnd
        Dim sOutput As String = html
        Dim file As System.IO.StreamWriter
        Dim masir As String = TextBox1.Text & "tm\Archive\" + slink(i).ToString 

        file = My.Computer.FileSystem.OpenTextFileWriter(masir, True)

        file.Write(html)

        file.Close()
    Next
```

Comment: Yes it is possible, have a look a multi threading.  Async patterns or background workers

Comment: @Hursey thank you. please  help more

Comment: Hursey already told you what you need to look into. Once you have done that and if you have a specific problem, come back and post about that problem.

Comment: I think the examples in the MSDN docs on `Async` and task-oriented parallelism are close to if not identical to what you want to do.

Comment: @Hursey. I  study multi threading. and Async patterns and background workers. But I was confused.  Please help to get started.

Comment: @Slugsie  I study multi threading. and Async patterns and background workers. But I was confused. Please help to get started

Comment: @Craig  I study multi threading. and Async patterns and background workers. But I was confused. Please help to get started

Comment: @AGH Maybe your best bet is to have a go, if it doesn't work post a new question with the specific problems you encounter

Comment: @AGH There are plenty of examples out there that show at least 80% of what you need. Try them out then get back to us with specific problems.

Comment: @Slugsie I searched the internet a lot but I could not find suitable examples. Please give me the address of some suitable examples. Thank you.

Comment: @AGH https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.threadpool?view=net-5.0 or https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.task-1?view=net-5.0